# Is "since" correct in the following text?

Tags: grammar

I know we can use "since" to give a reason for something.
Having said that, please specify all the grammatical and conceptual bugs of this text:

> "**Since** I found out, you my darling friends are trying hard to become
>   great doctors, I decided to choose an interesting subject; I mean a
>   topic that you are very interested in."

Answer (score 1):

> Since I found out, you my darling friends are trying hard to become great doctors, I decided to choose an interesting subject; I mean a topic that you are very interested in.

The word **since** is used correctly. However, the first comma is used incorrectly. And there should be a comma after **you** and **friends**.

---

First, let's look at the incorrect usage of the comma in:

*Since I found out, you my darling friends are trying hard to become great doctors*

'*Since I found out*' serves as an introduction to what the author found out. The author discloses that information in the following clause. To join two clauses, in this case, **that** should be used in place of the **comma**.

The correct sentence would be:

*Since I found out **that** you my darling friends are trying hard to become great doctors*

However, in informal and spoken English you can omit **that**. So, this is also correct:

*Since I found out you my darling friends are trying hard to become great doctors*

---

Now, let's look at the missing commas in:

*you my darling friends are trying hard to become great doctors*

There are two places where a comma should've been used—after **you** and after **friends**. The reason is that '*my darling and friends*' is not a part of the main sentence; it is an extra element of information about the word **you**. It provides the additional information to the reader about whom the author is referring to when he says **you**.

And this is not part of the main sentence because the sentence is still complete without these words:

*Since I found out that you are trying hard to become great doctors, I decided to...*

So, a comma is used to separate the extra information which is not part of the main sentence.

---

The final revision of your sentence should be this:

> Since I found out that you, my darling friends, are trying hard to become great doctors, I decided to choose an interesting subject; I mean a topic that you are very interested in.